# android ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false) does not prevent listView from refreshing

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with an arrayadapter. I want to refresh the adapter when I entirely fill in my array of items and only at this time. I know that notifyDataSetChanged() will be automatically called after methods such as add, addAll, remove, insert or clear but I think there might be a bug in my case.
Here is a simple snippet of code that should work. I mean in this case the adapter should not notify its ListView and content sould not be displayed (but content is displayed on my device).

```
ArrayList<MenuFragmentItem> menu = buildMenu();
MenuAdapter mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, MenuFragment.this);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.addAll(menu);
//      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); SAME RESULT IF I REMOVE THIS LINE, CONTENT IS DISPLAYED
```

Any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `ListView` source code, you'll see that `setAdapter` sets `mDataChanged` and calls `requestLayout`, which will schedule a layout. Your adapter won't be read back until that layout occurs, which will be after your `clear` and `addAll` code executes.

http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/3661101005c6527dfd384d0c88c4a3b68ee208af/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java

There are also several other ways to cause `mDataChanged` to be set to true and a new `requestLayout` call, such as checking, focusing, or selecting an item. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` just makes that happen immediately:

http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/3661101005c6527dfd384d0c88c4a3b68ee208af/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java#line772

```
    public void onChanged() {
        mDataChanged = true;
        ...
        requestLayout();
    }
```