# arrayadapter setnotifyonchange(false) not working

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to do something very similar to this post [android ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false) does not prevent listView from refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881093/android-arrayadapter-setnotifyonchangefalse-does-not-prevent-listview-from-ref) but the answer given does not seem to be very helpful.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.pos_textview, R.id.pos, posEntityList);
    posList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
    posEntityList.clear();
```

I've tried many things but it will still clear the arrayadapter and nothing will show in the list. I've tried setNotifyOnChange before setting the adapter too and it still doesn't work. I am trying to clear the given arraylist because I want to repopulate it with different results somewhere else. I don't think I want to use notifyDataSetChanged() for this because I don't want the listview cleared or refreshed. I am using the same arraylist multiple times for the same arrayadapter, so I do need to use clear().

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` will refresh listview. this will not clear listview. remove this  `arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false)`
    `posEntityList.clear()` and try

Comment: i am creating multiple adapters for multiple list views so i don't think I need notifyDataSetChanged(). I don't want to clear listview or refresh it, just clear the array in the arrayadapter without it changing the listview after the adapter is set.

Comment: @Raghunandan I need to use arraylist.clear() because I'm using the same arraylist multiple times for the same adapter. If I don't clear it, I get results tacked on to each other when I instantiate the adapter with the arraylist again.